# Encoding MOV video using windows azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to encode .mov video using windows azure media services. I am getting "File type or codec not supported" error. I tried all presets, but none of them are working.

Comment: You didn't provide any details about what you tried, your code, etc. Having said that: There's already a question that seems like a duplicate of this, from a year ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960997/azure-media-services-3gp-file-returns-error-file-type-or-codec-not-supported - have you looked at that?

Comment: It's the same sample code which you find everywhere for uploading videos using windows azure media service

Answer (score 1):

There is a easier fix for this. We don't accept files with .mov, however, if it is H.264, you could change extension to .Mp4, and rerun the encoding present. It should just work.

Comment: Thank you Mingfei, that worked! But there are some vidoes like .avi and .3gp where I am still getting error while encoding.

Comment: Hi Devesh, could you send me your video file to yanmf at microsoft.com? I can ask my encoding team to take a look.

Comment: Hey Mingfei, this is random, it works for certain videos and throws error for some videos.

There is one more issue, I am getting error **"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error"** when I try to upload large vidoes (25 MB). I am trying to upload the sample wildlife.wmv video which comes with windows.

Comment: That doesn't sound common. If you could email me your account, i could ask my engineers to pull the log.

Comment: Hey Mingfei,
I am still getting the same error for large video files.

Answer (score 0):

Azure media services now supports .mov. I followed this example and the orientation for the encodings was correct.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/media-services/media-services-dotnet-encode-with-media-encoder-standard.md